# Count tweets by user

Tags: twitter, counter

I have been scraping tweets with the hashtag mooc (massive online open courses). I now want to  identify the users who sent the tweets and a count of the number of tweets by each of them

This is how I identify the user:

```
for page in range(1,16):

url='http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=mooc&rpp=100'+str(page)
file=urllib.urlopen(url)
search = json.load(file)
for entry in search['results']:
     pprint.pprint(entry['from_user'])
```

This works fine with printing the data, but now I am struggling to store this data, instead of printing it, in order to count the tweets by each user.

```
import collections
y=collections.Counter(users)
print y
```

Also any other ideas on how to count the tweets by user are welcome!